# When are changes like deletions of tables reflected in BigQuery INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES and can an update be forced

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

To find all tables that exist in my project, I run the following query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `region-eu`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

However, when I delete a table and run this query again, the table is still in the results.
I noticed that it is still there after a few hours, but when I checked on the next day, it isn't in the results anymore. I couldn't find information about this behaviour in the docs, so my questions are:

- Is there a specific time or interval when the results of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` are updated?
- Can the query somehow be forced to retrieve the most up to date version of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`?